How to select all possible moves and pass another values in benchmark using Freemarker
Is there any way to pass value using Freemarker that indicates to select all possible moves in the selectedCountLimit and i want to pass another value for example 100 ?
for instance:
    <#list [100,all possible moves ?] as selectedCountLimit>
    <solverBenchmark>
       .
       .
      
     <selectedCountLimit>${selectedCountLimit}</selectedCountLimit>
       .
       .
      
    </solverBenchmark>
     </#list>

